# Why is Docusign Showing access Error?

Tags: docusign

I have enabled the Docusign button from the Layout tab under Docusign admin Tab.
When I Click on the "Send to Docusign" button on an account , a new page with the following error loads up

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured docusign correctly. it looks like a you are missing some [configuration](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-configure-dfs)

Comment: I am just testing , Docusign was already installed by someone.
When i started I didnt have the need to sign up or login when i clicked on the docusign admin tab.

All I did from my side was Add the desktop button on the account and contact layout.From there on clicking the send to docusign button i have this error open up.

I am a system admin user.

What possible configuration have i missed from my side?

Comment: check You are logged in Docusign and authenticate it.

Comment: it doesnt ask me for log in when i click on the docusign admin tab, so i am guessing i am logged in, right?

Comment: Do you have a DocuSign account? As far as I know, you will need to have a DocuSign account as well to be able to access it in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes , it was related to the docusign account, i hadn't created that.Its all working as it should be after the docusign account creation.
Thanks everyone for the time.